# Might a pacman -Syu have changed polkitd's password?

Tags: arch-linux

I've had quite a lot ssh bruteforce attacks on my server(Arch Linux).

I recently checked the auth log in which I found one suspicous entry (but no sucessful login by anyone that wasn't me):

```
passwd[#####]: password for 'polkitd' changed by 'root'
```

I am quite confident that I didn't change it myself as I'm not using polkit. But I think that i ran a pacman -Syu that day. Also polkitd is not running and no process sarted by the polkit user is running. Could it be that pacman was responsible for that?

Comment: You could check the `install` scripts in `/var/lib/pacman`. `find . -name install -exec grep -l passwd "{}" \;` should find the files that have `passwd` and you have to investigate those then.

Comment: @Thomas thanks a lot for the tip! `passwd -l polkitd &>/dev/null` in `./local/polkit-0.113+29+g3272a98-1/install` was the deal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pacman actually did change the password for polkit. It seems to be a security improvement.

In order to check this, I did the following (thanks to @Thomas):

```
find /var/lib/pacman -name install -exec grep -l passwd "{}" \;
```

Which gave me a list of files; one of them was `./local/polkit-0.113+29+g3272a98-1/install`

A quick inspection showed that there was a line `passwd -l polkitd &>/dev/null`

Which explains everything.